# My cursor is glitching when I use blender with my Wacom - is this a known issue?

Tags: error

I'm using Blender, on Win11 Prox64, with a Wacom Intuos 5 tablet and my cursor is glitching. Is there something I can do to eliminate this problem?

Video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r5EW1xAwhb4EREmrFWv1R4OEwgZd-oMC/view?usp=drive_link

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you saying you could not understand my question without viewing the video? As my question states - it's a cursor that's glitching out, how much more specificity do you require?

Comment: Yes, try posting some screenshots of the issue, so people don't have to go to another site or watch a video. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)